# Regex to ensure no whitespace before character

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to ensure that, say, `[1170]` has actual alphabetical characters beforehand, such as `NetworkManager[1170]` rather than whitespaces. I tried to use `\S[[].*[]]`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What results did you see?

Comment: Can you explain? Maybe provide some cases of inputs and outputs you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?i)(?<=[a-z])\[[^\[\]]*\]
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iI1mS9/3)

Explanation:

- `(?i)` case-insensitive matching
- `(?<=[a-z])` positive lookback: must be preceded by a character in `[a-z]`
- `\[` literal `[`
- `[^\[\]]` match any character but `[` or `]`
- `*` zero or more times
- `\]` literal `]`

Comment: You might either want to add a case-insensitivity marker, or use `[A-Za-z]`, as the OP's example uses `NetworkManager`.

Comment: @Joanna Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the whole string and ensure there are only numbers in the brackets, then try this:

```
\w+\[[0-9]+\]
```

You can [fiddle around here](https://regex101.com/r/jH4yT0/1)

here `\w+` selects the word and allows no whitespace

then `\[` selects the left bracket literally

for the numbers i used `[0-9]+` which selects only numbers

and finally `\]` to select the right bracket

if you would want to select the word and the numbers separately, then just add brackets to the word and the number part:

```
(\w+)\[([0-9]+)\]
```

You then have the word in the first match and the numbers in the second.

Answer (score 0):

try with the following RegEx

```
\w+\[\d+\]
```

where `\w+` selects one or more word character (no whitespaces), immediately followed by the `\[` literal character, followed by `\d+` one or more digits (no other characters, no whitespaces) and ending with the `\]` literal character.